# Basic music player - next and previous button

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

this is my last post about any kind of music player ever but I really need help. Im working on basic android music player application and Im having trouble to create NEXt and PREVIOUS buttons. So i pretty pretty please if anyone can get me out of that.I have tried something more about that downhere THANK YOU. I have created this yet:

Main Application Java file

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final int UPDATE_FREQUENCY = 500;
    private static final int STEP_VALUE = 4000;
    private MediaCursorAdapter mediaAdapter = null;
    private TextView selectedFile= null;
    private SeekBar seekbar = null;
    private MediaPlayer player = null;
    private ImageButton playButton = null;
    private ImageButton previousButton = null;
    private  ImageButton nextButton = null;
    private boolean isStarted = true;
    private  String currentFile = "";
    private boolean isMovingseekBar = false;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable updatePositionRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public  void run() {
            updatePosition();

        }
    };





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1);




     selectedFile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectedfile);
        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
        previousButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        nextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);

        player = new MediaPlayer();

        player.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion);
        player.setOnErrorListener(onError);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChanged);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (null != cursor) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cursor);
            setListAdapter(mediaAdapter);
            playButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
            nextButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
            previousButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected  void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position,long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
        currentFile = (String) view.getTag();
        startPlay(currentFile);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();

        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        player.release();

        player = null;
    }
    private  void startPlay(String file) {
        selectedFile.setText(file);
        seekbar.setProgress(0);

        player.stop();
        player.reset();

        try {
            player.setDataSource(file);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        seekbar.setMax(player.getDuration());
        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

        updatePosition();

        isStarted = true;

    }

    private void stopPlay() {
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
        seekbar.setProgress(0);

        isStarted = false;
    }
    private void updatePosition() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);

//        seekbar.setSecondaryProgressTintMode(player.getCurrentPosition());
        handler.postDelayed(updatePositionRunnable, UPDATE_FREQUENCY);
    }


    private class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

        MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c){
            super(context, layout,c,
                    new String[] {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION},
                    new int[] {R.id.displayname, R.id.title,R.id.duration});
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view,Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
            TextView duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);

            name.setText(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));

            title.setText(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE)));

            view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
        }
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

            bindView(v, context, cursor);

            return v;
        }
    }



    private View.OnClickListener onButtonClick  = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.play: {
                    if (player.isPlaying()) {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
                        player.pause();
                        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                    } else {
                        if (isStarted) {
                            player.start();
                            playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                            updatePosition();
                        } else {
                            startPlay(currentFile);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.next: {
                    int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() + STEP_VALUE;

                    if (seekto < player.getDuration())
                        seekto = player.getDuration();
                    player.pause();
                    player.seekTo(seekto);
                    player.start();

                    break;
                }
                case R.id.previous: {
                    int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() - STEP_VALUE;

                    if (seekto < player.getDuration())
                        seekto = player.getDuration();

                    player.pause();
                    player.seekTo(seekto);
                    player.start();

                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    };
    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            stopPlay();
        }
    };

    private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onError = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

            return false;
        }
    };


    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChanged = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            isMovingseekBar = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fomUser) {
            if (isMovingseekBar) {
                player.seekTo(progress);
                Log.i("OnSeekBarChangeListener", "onProgressChange");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            isMovingseekBar = true;
        }
    };

}
```

I have already did switch with NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons and I have tried to make them work BUT I ended up with getting at the and or beggining of the song not the NEXT or PREVIOUS.

Comment: Try using `case R.id.next:{int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() + STEP_VALUE;   
     if(seekto > player.getDuration())
      seekto = player.getDuration();
     
     player.pause();
     player.seekTo(seekto);
     player.start();
     
     break;
    }
    case R.id.prev:
    {
     int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() - STEP_VALUE;
     
     if(seekto < 0)
      seekto = 0;
     
     player.pause();
     player.seekTo(seekto);
     player.start();
     
     break;
    }`. I haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: it doesnt work the "step_value" should be some king of "point on next song" code